# Find a string within a quotation mark with regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to find a password enclosed by a quotation mark in the line of a network switch configuration but it didn't work. Can someone please help?. For example: I have a line in the config as:

```
set snmp v3 usm local-engine user Admin authentication-sha authentication-key "$aBCd./!Test"
```

I wrote a Regex statement like this but it does not work.

```
^set\s\snmp\sv3\s\usm\slocal-engine\suser\sAdmin\sAuthentication-sha\sauthentication-key\s[0-9A-Za-z$./!.*+]     

^set\s\snmp\sv3\s\usm\slocal-engine\suser\sAdmin\sAuthentication-sha\sauthentication-key\s[0-9A-Za-z$./!.*+]
```

nothing display

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern there are a few mistakes escaping `\u`, `\s` and an extra space.

You could repeat the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) 1+ times using `+` and use a capturing group

To also match `Authentication` you could make the match case insensitive, use an uppercase char or use `[aA]` to match both.

```
^set\ssnmp\sv3\susm\slocal-engine\suser\sAdmin\sAuthentication-sha\sauthentication-key\s"([0-9A-Za-z$./!.*+]+)"
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eset%5cssnmp%5csv3%5csusm%5cslocal-engine%5csuser%5csAdmin%5csAuthentication-sha%5csauthentication-key%5cs%22%28%5b0-9A-Za-z%24.%2f!.*%2b%5d%2b%29%22&i=set+snmp+v3+usm+local-engine+user+Admin+authentication-sha+authentication-key+%22%24aBCd.%2f!Test%22&o=im) | [Powershell demo](https://tio.run/##Zc9Ba8JAEAXge37FmC5oGzYqnjz0kBZ6Kwj2VFdhiEOyNNmEnUmK/vl0kyKUehreu3xv2uabPJdUVcOg9uLhGeZMAuzqFvoNdFxD1eRYaXKFdRQK8pCda@sAOynJic1RbOM0l/i/@qILxApfXs/pcvZBLDHMI7VDEfJupE7BMjxihvuN4cAZ/uuNFXnDkxjOHWn43jS8iA8rvc30J@qrCnb6lByT@DHgNUpeBnp6Vv@m26JIvY@Z@LA@wgO8Wc8CObbSeesKKHzTtcPwAw)

If the double quotes should be part of your result you could add them to the capturing group.

```
("[0-9A-Za-z$./!.*+]+")
```

[image]

For example

```
$Str = 'set snmp v3 usm local-engine user Admin authentication-sha authentication-key "$aBCd./!Test" '
$Pattern = '^set\ssnmp\sv3\susm\slocal-engine\suser\sAdmin\sAuthentication-sha\sauthentication-key\s("[0-9A-Za-z$./!.*+]+")'
$match = $Str -match $Pattern
$Matches[1] # First capturing group
```

Output

```
"$aBCd./!Test"
```

Comment: I tried ("[0-9A-Za-z$./!.*+]+") to also capture the double quotation mark but it gave me an error. The error msg said "You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator + missing ']' after array index expression.  I also tried to put the double quotation mark inside the bracket like (["0-9A-Za-z%./!.*+"]+ but still didn't work

Comment: @user12042581 I have added an example script how to get the capturing group including the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

this will match anything between double quotes, but it presumes there is only ONE such pair. the captured group is in the `$Matches` automatic variable @ index 1.

```
$InStuff = 'set snmp v3 usm local-engine user Admin authentication-sha authentication-key "$aBCd./!Test"'

$Null = $InStuff -match '.+"(.+)"'

$Matches[1]
```

output = `$aBCd./!Test`